# How to write a GeoRSS that can be used for "google.maps.KmlLayer"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, rss, atom-feed, georss

1. The [atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) is:

   ```
   <title>Example Feed</title>
   <subtitle>A subtitle.</subtitle>
   <link href="http://example.org/feed/" rel="self" />
   <link href="http://example.org/" />
   <id>urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b91C-0003939e0af6</id>
   <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
   <author>
       <name>John Doe</name>
       <email>johndoe@example.com</email>
   </author>

   <entry>
       <title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>
       <link href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03" />
       <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03.html"/>
       <link rel="edit" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03/edit"/>
       <id>urn:uuid:1225c695-cfb8-4ebb-aaaa-80da344efa6a</id>
       <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
       <summary>Some text.</summary>
   </entry>
   ```
2. The [GeoRSS](http://georss.org/Main_Page) is:

   < georss:point>45.256 -71.92< /georss:point>
3. The `google.maps.KmlLayer` is:

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.496675,-102.65625);
   var myOptions = {
     zoom: 4,
     center: myLatlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

   var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=322338@N20〈=en-us&format=feed-georss');
   georssLayer.setMap(map);

How can I create a useful GeoRSS that contains 1 and 2 for 3?